# Can C++ pattern of making structs to 'correspond' types be emulated in Haskell (template specialization)?

Tags: c++, haskell, template-specialization, compile-time, static-typing

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Corresponding;

template <>
struct Corresponding<int> {
    using CorrespondingT = boost::multiprecison::cpp_int;
};
template <typename T> using GetCorresponding = typename Corresponding<T>::CorrespondingT;
```

This can be used as

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<GetCorresponding<int>, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>); // true
```

Where `Corresponding<T>` is the struct containing an alias with a corresponding type of `T`, resolved at compile-time.
Another example of this is `std::remove_ptr_t<T*>` which corresponds to `T`

Can I do something similar in Haskell, e.g.

```hs
iAmAnInteger :: getCorresponding Int -- Integer
```

?

I'm not familiar Haskell's capabilities with compile-time types but is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not fluent in C++, so I'm not 100% sure what your example code is doing, but at a first glance type families and equalities seem similar.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Corresponding a
type instance Corresponding Int = Integer

foo :: Corresponding Int ~ Integer => ()
foo = () -- compiles

bar :: Corresponding Int ~ Bool => ()
bar = () -- type error at any use site

baz :: Corresponding Int
baz = toInteger 3 -- compiles

quux :: Corresponding Int
quux = False -- type error
```